# servlet and mysql connection error ClassNotFoundException

Tags: mysql, servlets

---> Hello all, I am trying to connect servlet with mysql  but I dont know why am I getting ClassNotFoundException? It is occuring in class.forName line. Database Name is trial1, table name is data2 with columns ID,Name,Salary. Please Help.

```
        *import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.PrintWriter;
        import java.sql.DriverManager;
        import java.sql.SQLException;
        import java.util.Properties;
        import javax.servlet.ServletException;
        import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
        import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
        import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet;
        import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
        /**
         * Servlet implementation class dbHandling
         */
        @WebServlet("/dbHandling")
        public class dbHandling extends HttpServlet {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            /**
             * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
             */
            public dbHandling() {
                super();
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }
            /**
             * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
             */
            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

                  final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
                  final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/trial1";
                  //  Database credentials
                  final String USER = "root";
                  final String PASS = "root";
                  Connection conn = null ; 
                  // Set response content type
                  response.setContentType("text/html");
                  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                  String title = "Database Result";
                  String docType =
                    "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
                     "transitional//en\">\n";
                     out.println(docType +
                     "<html>\n" +
                     "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
                     "<body bgcolor=\"red\">\n" +
                     "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n");
                     Statement stmt = null;

                     try{

                     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();/*This is    where exception is occuring*/
                     conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
                     stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
                     String sql;
                     sql = "SELECT * from data2";
                     System.out.println(sql);
                     ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                     while(rs.next()){
                        int id  = rs.getInt("id");
                        int age = rs.getInt("age");
                        String salary = rs.getString("salary");
                        out.println("ID: " + id + "<br>");
                        out.println(", Age: " + age + "<br>");
                        out.println(", First: " + salary + "<br>");
                     }
                     out.println("</body></html>");
                     rs.close();
                     stmt.close();
                     conn.close();
                  }catch(SQLException se){
                     se.printStackTrace();
                  }catch(Exception e){
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  }finally{
                     try{
                        if(stmt!=null)
                           stmt.close();
                     }catch(SQLException se2){
                     }
                     try{
                        if(conn!=null)
                        conn.close();
                     }catch(SQLException se){
                        se.printStackTrace();
                     }
                  } 
            }
        }
```

Comment: down load the latest mysql driver jar file and place it on your project classpath.

Comment: Add the compleate stacktrace please, so wie can see wich class is not found.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the application is looking for a Class that it can not find and as you have correctly put it the error is on

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

This is because the System is trying to load the mysql connector class which you have not placed in your classpath. Please download the Latest Jar file and place it in your class path. For more on how to add jar to a classpath see [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html)